# xml document as root-to-leafs tree in r

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I am trying to represent the tree structure of an XML document as a list of paths, or a list of concatenated node names. For example:

```
<node id="A">
   <node id = "AA">
       <node id = "AAA"></node>
   </node>
   <node id = "AB">
   </node>
   <node id = "AC">
   </node>
</node>
```

Should convert to this:

```
//A/AA/AAA 
//A/AB
//A/AC
```

Or this:

```
A, AA, AAA 
A, AB
A, AC
```

I have found examples in other languages:

[Get a list of all root-to-leaf paths in a DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752613/get-a-list-of-all-root-to-leaf-paths-in-a-dom-tree)

But I am not sure how to iterate through nodes in R. I am using the xml2 package.

Has anyone solved this problem? Asking for a friend.

Comment: Well, maybe `xml %>% read_xml() %>% xml_find_all('//*') %>% xml_path()`, but it's not quite giving you what you expect.

Comment: That works! I just posted as a solution below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested by @alistaire in the comments above works here.

Just remember to strip your namespace.

```
library( dplyr )
library( xml2 )

dat <- read_xml( "https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201541349349307794_public.xml" )
dat %>% xml_find_all( '//*') %>% xml_path()
#  [1] "/*"                            "/*/*[1]"                      
#  [3] "/*/*[1]/*[1]"                  "/*/*[1]/*[2]"                 
#  [5] "/*/*[1]/*[3]"                  "/*/*[1]/*[3]/*[1]" 


xml_ns_strip( dat )
dat %>% xml_find_all( '//*') %>% xml_path()
#  [1] "/Return"                                                                                               
#  [2] "/Return/ReturnHeader"                                                                                  
#  [3] "/Return/ReturnHeader/ReturnTs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the "xml2" package.  I wrote this function to find the valve at each node, but in your case we are just looking to identify the attribute "id" for each node.
The intent is to to find all of the top level nodes without children and extract their values, then move to the nodes with children.  Then repeat this function recursively until the greatest descendent nodes have been found and processed.

```
library(xml2)
file<-read_xml('<node id="A">
   <node id = "AA">
               <node id = "AAA"></node>
               </node>
               <node id = "AB">
               </node>
               <node id = "AC">
               </node>
               </node>')

findchildren<-function(nodes, df){
  numchild<-sapply(nodes, function(x){length(xml_children(x))})
  #extract out the attribute, value and parents
  xmlattr<-xml_attr(nodes[numchild==0], "id")
  #xmlvalue<-xml_text(nodes[numchild==0])  #value of node
  xmlpath<-sapply(nodes[numchild==0], function(x) {toString(rev(xml_attr(xml_parents(x), "id")))})

  #dftemp<-data.frame(xmlattr, xmlvalue, xmlpath)
  dftemp<-data.frame(xmlpath, xmlattr)

  #merge results back to master df
  df<-rbind(df, dftemp)
  print(dim(df))  #Print statement for status
  #End of recursion
  if (sum(numchild)>0){
    findchildren(xml_children(nodes[numchild>0]), df) }
  else{ return(df)}
}

df<-data.frame()
df<-findchildren(xml_children(file), df) 
apply(df, 1, toString)
```

This function outputs a 2 column data frame.  The first column is the xml path to the node in the second column.  I used the `apply` command to merge these 2 columns together for your final solution.  The order to the final list not based on the original construction of the document but on listing the parents, then children, the grandchildren nodes....
This function repetitively calls `rbind` not the most efficient method but acceptable if the number of children levels are not too great.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful for understanding how to apply functions over nodesets and select based upon attributes. Clever recursion as well. See above for a simple solution.